# Jenkins Build error - groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: fileLoader for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, groovy

**Objective:**
we have a file in our application folder named as JenkinsFile. From that File, we are trying to call a groovy script file which contains the pipeline script of Jenkins build and deploy. The groovy script file is in seperate GITLAB repository.

**Jenkins file code:**

```
#!groovy
@Library("usingALibrary") _

def COMMON_REPO       = 'GITLAB_URL'
def REDIRECTED_SCRIPT = 'buildJenkinsPipelineScript.groovy'
def CREDENTIALS_ID    = 'credentials'

def jenkinsFile
jenkinsFile = fileLoader.fromGit(REDIRECTED_SCRIPT, COMMON_REPO, 'master', CREDENTIALS_ID, 'maven')
try{
    jenkinsFile.start()
}
catch(NullPointerException e)
{
    echo "Script threw a NullPointerException but it will be omitted."
}
```

**Problem:**

The error that we get while building in jenkins is:

```
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: fileLoader for class: groovy.lang.Binding
        at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:291)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:295)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
        at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:9)
        at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor609.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:66)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone please suggest the solution of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing [File Loader Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-remote-loader-plugin)

> The plugin adds a global fileLoader DSL variable, which provides methods for loading Pipeline objects from remote sources.